# Google Chrome: Have different settings on different computers?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-workspace

I use Google Chrome and have specific settings for it and which apps I have downloaded for it. I use it with many of my computers (two laptops, desktop, phone, work desktop, etc.). I have a LOT of apps on my Google Chrome.

Now, my one laptop is slow and is only used for simple tasks like getting on the internet and surfing the web. When I open Chrome, it, of course, runs ALL the apps I downloaded and loads EVERYTHING. Just the very task of opening Chrome, takes a while, let alone opening multiple tabs. Now, this laptop is only being used for simple tasks and more than half the stuff I have downloaded on Chrome, I don't use on this laptop.

Is there anyway on Chrome to remove some of those apps ONLY on the Chrome browser on my slow laptop?

I would like of other computers that use Chrome, to continue syncing with whatever I do, but only have one computer that is "partially" synced.

I'm figuring that if I don't have as many apps running in the background, that it won't suck up much of the CPU, so I can do some other small tasks at a reasonable speed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Chrome on your slow laptop, open **Advanced sync settings** (chrome://settings/syncSetup), turn off "Sync everything", and uncheck anything you do not want to sync to the laptop. This will only affect the laptop where you change these settings.

[image: Chrome Advanced sync settings]

After unchecking "Apps" in this list, you will experience the following behavior:

- Any apps you install on another computer will not automatically install on the slow laptop.
- Any apps you install on the slow laptop will not automatically install on your other computers.
- Any apps you remove from another computer will not automatically be removed from the slow laptop.
- Any apps you remove from the slow laptop will not automatically be removed from your other computers.

Answer (score 1):

This is an rather old question, but still something that have been bugging me. So here is my own two cents.

You might be able to use an another extension to do this. I myself have been switching between these two plugins: 
"[Extensions Manager (aka Switcher)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-manager-aka-sw/lpleipinonnoibneeejgjnoeekmbopbc?hl=en)"

> Handy extensions, applications & themes manager.
>   Light popup manager to enable, disable, uninstall extensions, applications quickly and easy.

or "[SimpleExtManager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleextmanager/kniehgiejgnnpgojkdhhjbgbllnfkfdk?hl=en)"

> A simple menu to enable, disable and access options of extensions.
>   Another addition to the 'Simple' series. This time its an extension
>   manager.
>
> Features include:
>
> - basic function to enable/disable, access options and uninstall extensions via popup
> - customize the popup
> - ability to create extension groups
> - enable/disable extension groups via popup and right-click menu
> - event page enabled

I like both of the extensions, but haven't gotten to a point where I can say which one I like the most. Both of them are going through a lot of development and are updated frequently.

Comment: Why you repeat your answer? http://superuser.com/a/942289/527571

Comment: @Woeitg becuase at that time, the answer wasn't marked as a duplicate even though I reported it as is