# Maintain different set of extensions in Chrome, on different PCs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I use my `GMail` account both at home, and in the office, to sign in to `Chrome`. In my PC at home, I have a set of `Extensions` that I use a lot, like `YouTube Actions`, `AdBlocker`, `HoverZoom`, etc. But on my Mac in the office, I'd like to maintain a different set of `Extensions` like `JSONParser`, `Any.Do`, etc.

Is there a way to keep them differentiated?

Comment: Can you sync the extensions the disable them locally or does Chrome sync the enable/disable status?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, Chrome also syncs the enabled/disabled status. The answer of Keltari works (disabling the syncing of extensions).

Comment: @Rik I hate good at times give us 100% control of what is synced please....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can turn off extension syncing in Chrome.

Go to Settings -> Sign in -> Advanced sync settings, and uncheck Extensions

Comment: I also turned off "sync settings" on my work PC, so I can sync extensions and settings among several home computers without affecting the work PC.

Answer (score 3):

This is an rather old question, but still something that have been bugging me. So here is my own two cents.

You might be able to use an another extension to do this. I myself have been switching between these two plugins: 
"[Extensions Manager (aka Switcher)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-manager-aka-sw/lpleipinonnoibneeejgjnoeekmbopbc?hl=en)"

> Handy extensions, applications & themes manager.
>   Light popup manager to enable, disable, uninstall extensions, applications quickly and easy.

or "[SimpleExtManager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleextmanager/kniehgiejgnnpgojkdhhjbgbllnfkfdk?hl=en)"

> A simple menu to enable, disable and access options of extensions.
>   Another addition to the 'Simple' series. This time its an extension
>   manager.
>
> Features include:
>
> - basic function to enable/disable, access options and uninstall extensions via popup
> - customize the popup
> - ability to create extension groups
> - enable/disable extension groups via popup and right-click menu
> - event page enabled

I like both of the extensions, but haven't gotten to a point where I can say which one I like the most. Both of them are going through a lot of development and are updated frequently.