# Can I use the same Google Chrome sign on for 2 different computers and have different settings on each computer?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a home PC and a PC at work and I used to have each set up to load different pages on start up, but recently our IT department replaced my CPU and when they did, they didn't care to save anything I had set up all these years.  So I went to re-create and I don't remember how I was able to have the two different settings and now whatever I set up on one ends up the same on the other??  Any idea on how I was able to set these up separately before?  I know for sure I did not "add a person" or use any other identity when I set it up.  Help!

Comment: does this work? untick things here under 'choose what to sync'  then maybe the different computers will have their own settings http://superuser.com/questions/552037/google-chrome-have-different-settings-on-different-computers

Comment: Just don't sync the data...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no. Using your Google login on both devices will have them sync, such as sharing tabs, etc. Use a different login for each, or simply choose not to sync.